# array of json object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jasper-reports

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHkBL.png)    [
      {
        "id": "901651",
        "supplier_id": "180",
        "price": "18.99",
        "product_id": "books",
        "name": "bookmate",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1423326",
        "supplier_id": "180",
        "price": "53.99",
        "product_id": "books",
        "name": "classmate",
        "quantity": "5"
      }
    ]

"

```
[{"id":"3811088","supplier_id":"2609","price":"22.99","product_id":"book","name":"classmate","quantity":"10"}]"
```

I have my purchased books details stored in an array of json object in a field named items in table purchase_list. This corresponds to only one order.Field may contain single or multiple orders. There are multiple orders like this. how can i get the total number of each type of book purchased and the type of books only using pgsql query to generate jasper report. for eg: classmate:15, bookmate:1

Comment: which attribute tells the type of book?..

Comment: "name": "classmate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can unnest array and aggregate it:

```
 t=# with c(j) as (values('[
  {
    "id": "901651",
    "supplier_id": "180",
    "price": "18.99",
    "product_id": "books",
    "name": "bookmate",
    "quantity": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1423326",
    "supplier_id": "180",
    "price": "53.99",
    "product_id": "books",
    "name": "classmate",
    "quantity": "5"
  }
,{"id":"3811088","supplier_id":"2609","price":"22.99","product_id":"book","name":"classmate","quantity":"10"}]'::jsonb))
, agg as (select jsonb_array_elements(j) jb from c)
, mid as (select format('"%s":"%s"',jb->>'name',sum((jb->>'quantity')::int)) from agg group by jb->>'name')
select format('{%s}',string_agg(format,','))::jsonb from mid;
                format
--------------------------------------
 {"bookmate": "1", "classmate": "15"}
(1 row)
```

looks ugly, but gives the idea

Comment: thanks it works. but i cant hard code the values and the field is not jsonb.. my field name is items and table purchase_list. can you provide a solution for this.

Comment: column name is items and table purchase_list.

Comment: I will even help you doing all your work. but first please update your post with table structure and data sample. You can't be this lazy :)

Comment: This is an entry in items column where user buys 2 products at a time
[
  {
    "id": "901651",
    "supplier_id": "180",
    "price": "18.99",
    "product_id": "book",
    "name": "classmate",
    "quantity": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1423326",
    "supplier_id": "180",
    "price": "53.99",
    "product_id": "book",
    "name": "bookmate",
    "quantity": "5"
  }
]

Comment: items column elements are stored in text format. It is an array of json object

Comment: this is an entry in column items when user buys only 1 type of book.[
  {
    "id": "302487",
    "supplier_id": "104",
    "price": "26.99",
    "product_id": "books",
    "name": "papergrid",
    "quantity": "10"
  }
]

Comment: i have added screenshot of db.. please check... thanks in advance :) :) :)